# How to rate limit visitors voluntarily opening hundreds of tabs?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, security

I am recently facing an issue with some haters opening hundreds of tabs on my website to put it down. It's a Wordpress website hosted on a VPS with a 12 threads CPU and 48 GB memory with PHP 8.1. It uses LiteSpeed cache for both logged in and out users, with some private cache rules for ajax-based page fragments.

When they attack, the CPU load stay at 100% for multiple hours and the website is broken (with connections to the DB not working).

It's protected with Cloudflare free plan but the problem is that it's seen as legitimate visitors when it's not really. I can't find a clean solution to limite a single IP address to a maximum of XX requests per second or minute.

The only thing I found on stackoverflow is a PHP script to store vars in $_SESSION but I'd like to prevent this approach if you have something better to propose.

I asked the question on [webmasters.stacjexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/144157/how-to-rate-limit-visitors-voluntarily-opening-hundreds-of-tabs) but they kindly closed it since it's about programming for them so please do not send me to another stack-exchange subsite.

Comment: It's really not about programming, either. Cloudflare's free service does have rate limiting, which you can use to limit hits per IP in a certain amount of time. There are also Wordpress plugins that can do rate limiting for you, but that actually allows traffic to a certain point.

Comment: I'd say you'd be better handling it in the webserver than in PHP code, it can likely block or limit people more efficiently. Why not just block the IPs completely, if they're not desirable visitors?

Comment: That's a pretty hefty server that shouldn't have any issue with *hundreds* of requests. You need to start looking at where things are bottlenecking.

Comment: @ADyson I am trying to do that but they don't have a fixed address it seems.

Comment: Absolutely. Realistically it's probably not people literally opening tabs in browsers (that would be far too manual), but actually automated bots just sending HTTP requests from a script. And they will use VPNs and multiple servers to conceal their location and also to fool your blocking systems by using multiple different IP addresses. This is a pretty common DDOS (distributed denial of service) attack technique, and if you've got something like Cloudflare you should be able to configure it to combat that sort of thing - if it doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: That said, unless you have a very cheap / small server, and/or are sharing it with lots of other applications and sites, then "hundreds" of requests shouldn't really be a big problem for performance. Is that an accurate number you've reported to us, or just a guesstimate?

Comment: Your server sounds like it should be capable enough to deal with that most of the time. Perhaps they are making requests to URLs where the scripts take a long time to respond, and thus consume lots of resources simultaneously? And/or you have a setting reducing the number of simultaneous connections allowed? It's debugging time, I think. Make sure you've got really accurate stats, look for patterns in the URLs being requested, check your webserver and PHP settings, and look for performance bottlenecks in your code. And alongside that, look into what Cloudflare can do to help block these people

Comment: P.S. `I can't find a clean solution to limite a single IP address to a maximum of XX requests per second or minute`...I don't know why you'd want to allow these visitors to make _any_ requests at all??

Comment: P.P.S. https://www.cloudflare.com/en-gb/ddos/#DDoS-Page-Pricing-AS - I'm not familiar with the specifics but it says there that even on the free plan you can set up DDOS protection from your cloudflare dashboard. There's also a firewall

Comment: @ADyson for your PS, it's because I have no idea what is their IP address before they start attacking (they use IP randomizer like VPN or proxy). Next event they will attack is on Friday, I have set up Cloudflare, I will keep you posted.

Comment: `I have no idea what is their IP address before they start `...no, I don't imagine you would. DDOS protection shouldn't require that knowledge, if it's any use

Answer (score 2):

CloudFlare has rate limiting per IP, which wouldn't care whether the traffic is considered legitimate or not.

If you're using a framework, many (such as Laravel) have built-in rate limiting which typically uses middleware and a cache server (eg redis) to keep track of how many requests come from each IP - see https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/rate-limiting

As @ceejayoz says in the comments on the post, 'hundreds' of requests shouldn't be enough to bring down your site so it's probably a good time to have a look at bottlenecks in your code. For example, one frequent bottleneck is connecting to your database over a non-local IP.

Comment: I am using wordpress and LiteSpeed caching system.
Cloudflare rate limit for free plan allows only a 10 seconds period expiring after 10 seconds. Writing it, it might be enough, I will give it a try.
The next plan is $200/month which is quite expensive.
I currently display different parts of a web page with multiple AJAX request (wp ajax), if I understand what you are saying about the accesses to the DB I should probably regroup into a unique call per page.

Comment: @Niko don't group calls just to solve db query time. A call to a local db (ie using 127.0.0.1 or localhost) should take a couple of ms, but if you're calling it over a public network it can take many times that for each call. This is often the most overlooked issue when there are performance concerns.

Comment: I use `define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );` so I guess that no matter if I use $wpbd in the PHP loading the page or in an ajax call.
I am doing a lot of DateTime objects manipulation, I am rewriting the PHP to get the date directly in the SQL queries instead since it seems that there is definitely something creating CPU spikes.

Answer (score 1):

Cloudflare helped, and I decided to refactor some part of the website to limit the number of AJAX calls.
I wanted to load different parts of the pages asynchronously to make it looking more 2020 even if it's a PHP Wordpress, but looking at the difference of performance it seems to be a very bad idea.

Nevertheless, Cloudflare rate limiting has been triggered many times last night so it's definitely doing the job. I have read that Sucuri could also be a good alternative to Cloudflare, 10x cheaper.